# Is there a PPA for the latest Blender version?

Tags: ppa, blender

I am interested in trying out the Blender 2.54 beta, but  don't have the time or patience to download and install all of the dependencies for it and compile it myself.

Is there a PPA somewhere that I can use to obtain a pre-compiled package for it?

Comment: Linked question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110821/how-to-install-blender-from-the-official-website

Comment: @NathanOsman Please consider Tishere for the correct answer. Your chosen correct answer is no longer relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can also use [https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender](https://launchpad.net/%7Eirie/+archive/blender) which is another alternative to the 2.5.x and the 2.4.x

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender && sudo apt-get update`

For Blender 2.68.x - `sudo apt-get install blender`

For Blender 2.4.x - `sudo apt-get install blender2.4`

---

### Please note:

IRIE's PPA has not been updated for 6 months now, I have setup a new one here:

[https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender)

You can install Blender 2.73rc1 and update as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

Comment: That's a much better solution... that way I can have both installed.

Comment: NOTE: this works only for 10.10 and later.

Answer (score 16):

I've managed to find a PPA for version 2.53 beta:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cheleb/blender-svn && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/blender-253-beta-3d-graphics.html

Reference: [How to use PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Thanks! That'll be just great. Now that Launchpad supports daily builds, maybe we'll see more of these.

Comment: My only concern with using this PPA is that it updates Python 3 to Python 3.2. Not sure if this will cause more problems for other Python 3 applications.

Comment: It's closed now. I've sent a message with question to cheleb.

Comment: His answer is: "due to time constraints I cannot maintain that PPA any longer. However
there is still IRIE Shinsuke's excellent Blender PPA. He maintains
Blender 2.4 and 2.6 and does ~weekly updates. I am gonna use that
myself from now on.
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Best regards
Ralf"

Answer (score 8):

Given that IRIE's PPA has not been updated for 6 months now, I have setup a new one here:

https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender

You can install it and update as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

Comment: Please consider editing the current accepted answer to include your new PPA. That's how this site works. :-)