# Nvidia Current shows 304 driver but i require a 331 driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, nvidia-settings

I want to install CUDA toolkit 6 on my ubuntu 12.04.  While trying to install the nvidia driver, the command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

shows:

```
nvidia-304 nvidia-current nvidia-settings-304
```

But my graphic card is NVIDIA GeForce GT630M and as per the nvidia website it says it has 331.79 drivers.  I installed 331.79 driver using .run and the system doesn't seem to recognize it.

So can't I install 331.79? Why is my current driver still 304?

Comment: What Ubuntu is this?

Comment: This answer should be viewed as the definitive guide for all Ubuntu  NVIDIA installs: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 @Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install or upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 you can install nvidia-331, NVIDIA CUDA toolkit and the NVIDIA CUDA 5.5 Runtime library directly from the default Ubuntu repositories. libcudart5.5 is the package name of the NVIDIA CUDA runtime library. libcudart5.5 requires the nvidia-331 or more recent graphics driver. There is also an NVIDIA CUDA toolkit package (nvidia-cuda-toolkit) in the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 14.04, and like libcudart5.5 it is also version 5.5. Yes, I know the version in Ubuntu 14.04 is lagging behind NVIDIA CUDA toolkit 6 (See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04/462525#462525) for information about how to install NVIDIA CUDA toolkit 6).

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376760/can-not-properly-install-blender/376802#376802) has a screenshot showing that the NVIDIA CUDA runtime library is running on an Nvidia GeForce GT610 graphics card in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Unfortunately i am reverting back to ubuntu 12.04LTS and will try to install an older version of CUDA. Hopefully this won't be as painful as my previous encounters. Thanks for the Information.