# cant install cuda toolkit

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, blender

I followed the instructions per [this page](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/ubuntu/blender). Now, I get this error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-opencl-dev (= 5.5.22-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed or
                                opencl-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have a fresh install of ubuntu studio 64bit (with latest updates
just installed nvidia340.65
Graphics card Geforce GTX 750ti
not sure whats happening. but all I am trying to do is get blender to see my card so i can render with my gpu

Comment: [Here's how to enable CUDA with an NVIDIA graphics card in Ubuntu 14.04 with Blender](http://askubuntu.com/questions/376760/can-not-properly-install-blender/376802#376802). You don't need to download either the NVIDIA graphics driver or CUDA from the official websites. All the packages you need to use CUDA in Blender in Ubuntu 14.04 and onward are in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: If it is possible it is always better to install from Ubuntu's own sources. So the best solution here is indeed to follow the instructions from @karel instead of the one from your link.

Comment: followed karel's instructions to the letter. I still don't see the CUDA option in blender....

Comment: I suggest that you try it again, after you reboot the next time, in order to enable the NVIDIA driver and CUDA. Also you have to uninstall whatever NVIDIA and CUDA packages you downloaded from the official NVIDIA and the official CUDA websites before you install NVIDIA driver and CUDA packages from the Ubuntu Software Center. The NVIDIA driver from the official NVIDIA website includes its own uninstaller script to make it easy to uninstall it.

Comment: thanks for the response. I had no NVIDIA drivers installed before I followed your instructions....I started from a completely fresh install of ubuntu. and I also did reboot to enable the driver. also the recommended driver version for my card is 340.65. I dont know if that would make a difference or not. again, thanks (sorry if I seem to come off rude, I don't mean to)

Comment: The NVIDIA 340.65 driver is the package that is causing the unmet dependencies error message in my opinion. nvidia-331 is a very good graphics driver. First you have to uninstall the manually installed Nvidia version 340.65 graphics driver by following the instructions from [How to uninstall manually installed Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers) (try Luis Alvarado's answer first) and then reboot and install the nvidia-331 graphics driver and then reboot again to enable the nvidia-331 graphics driver.

Comment: ok. tried it again with a completely fresh ubuntu install. then i installed the NVIDIA driver and cuda lib, rebooted and when i went to switch in the additional drivers tab, it said no drivers available. but i opened up the NVidia xserver settings and it looks like it installed the drivers ok. installed blender, rebooted, opened blender... No luck! ugh!

Answer (score 6):

Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

That solved it for me on Windows 10's bash (with Ubuntu 14). Was getting the same error.