# Need help for my NIVIDIA driver installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have recently started using Ubuntu 16.04 Creative Studio & was trying to install an NVIDIA Geforce gt710 driver over the Ubuntu suggested driver (I had to, as Ubuntu was not accepting the (auto prompt) Nvidia driver & the Nouveau driver was running by default).

I downloaded the latest Nvidia driver (-375.66.run) from the NVIDIA site separately. Everything went fine after a couple of tries from help instructions I found online, I went to shell, disabled desktop manager, installed driver, updated intramfs, & (I thought) my Nvidia driver was installed & running. But software that requires GPU acceleration does not detect the card.

I see **Manually installed driver** in the **Additional Drivers Settings** and under **System Settings**, the proprietary NVIDIA & Noveau drivers are locked.

Does this sound like a faulty driver installation? What might be the correct process to get it running?

```
$ uname -r
4.8.0-42-lowlatency

$ find /lib/modules/ -name nvidia\*.ko\*
/lib/modules/4.8.0-40-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/nvidia/nvidiafb.ko
/lib/modules/4.8.0-42-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia-drm.ko
/lib/modules/4.8.0-42-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko
/lib/modules/4.8.0-42-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/nvidia/nvidiafb.ko
/lib/modules/4.8.0-42-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia-modeset.ko
/lib/modules/4.8.0-42-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia-uvm.ko

$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_drm              49152       2
nvidia_modeset     790528    3   nvidia_drm
nvidia                        12312576  41  nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper      167936     1   nvidia_drm
drm                            364544   5  nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper

$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [Geforce GT710 B] [10de:128b] (rev a1)
Subsystem: ZOTAK International (MCO) Ltd. GK208 [Geforce GT710 B] [19da:7326]
Kernel Driver in use: nvidia
Kernel Modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm,nvidia

$ /var/log/Xorg.0.log
bash: /var/log/Xorg.0.log: Permission Denied
```

Contents of the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file:

```
[    35.527] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[    35.527] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    35.527] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    35.527] Current Operating System: Linux gargoyle 4.8.0-42-lowlatency #45-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 8 22:57:02 UTC 2017 x86_64
[    35.527] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-42-lowlatency root=UUID=e0a48b04-05f1-44a1-9234-ecc861c9ea9f ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    35.527] Build Date: 02 November 2016  10:06:55PM
[    35.527] xorg-server 2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    35.527] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    35.527]     Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    35.527] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    35.527] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jul  1 11:54:09 2017
[    35.527] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    35.527] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    35.822] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    35.822] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    35.822] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    35.850] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    35.850] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    35.850] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    35.850] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    35.850] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    35.850] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    35.850] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    35.850] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    35.850]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.850] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    35.850]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.850] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    35.850]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.850] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    35.850]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.850] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    35.850]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.850] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    35.850] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    35.850] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    35.850] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    35.850] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    35.861] (II) Loader magic: 0x563403ace020
[    35.861] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    35.861]     X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    35.861]     X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    35.861]     X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    35.861]     X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    35.862] (++) using VT number 7

[    35.862] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    35.862] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    35.864] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:128b:19da:7326 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe8000000/134217728, 0xf2000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000dc00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    35.864] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    35.999] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    37.861] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    37.861]     compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    37.861]     Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    37.891] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  375.66  Mon May  1 14:28:39 PDT 2017
[    37.901] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    37.901] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    38.152] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    38.152]     compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    38.152]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    38.185] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  375.66  Mon May  1 14:03:26 PDT 2017
[    38.185] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    38.233] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    38.233] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    38.273] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    38.332] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    38.332]     compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    38.332]     ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    38.332] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    38.332] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    38.332] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    38.433] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    38.433]     compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    38.433]     ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    38.433] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    38.433] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    38.433] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    38.501] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    38.501] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    38.501] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    38.501] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    38.513] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    39.223] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[    39.223] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0 (boot)
[    39.223] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[    39.223] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[    39.224] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GT 710 (GK208) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    39.224] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[    39.224] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 80.28.a6.00.11
[    39.224] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 8X
[    39.254] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): connected
[    39.254] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    39.254] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    39.254] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    39.254] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    39.255] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    39.255] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    39.255] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    39.255] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    39.255] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    39.255] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    39.256] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    39.256] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    39.256] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    39.256] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    39.737] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    39.737] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    39.737] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1366 x 768
[    39.740] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (84, 84); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    39.740] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    39.740] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    39.741] (II) NVIDIA: Using 12288.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    39.741] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[    43.031] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    43.137] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    43.137] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[    43.137] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    43.138] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    43.138] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    43.138] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    43.138] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    43.138] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    43.138] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    43.139] (--) RandR disabled
[    43.156] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    43.165] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    43.165] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[    43.801] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    43.801] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    43.801] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    43.801] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    43.835] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    43.835]     compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 2.10.2
[    43.835]     Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    43.835]     ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[    43.835] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    43.835] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    43.835] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    43.835] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    43.835] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    43.835] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    43.835] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    43.835] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    43.835] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    43.835] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    43.835] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    43.835] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    43.835] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    43.835] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    43.835] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    43.835] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    43.835] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    43.835] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    43.835] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    43.835] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    43.835] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    43.835] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    43.835] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    43.835] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    43.836] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event8)
[    43.836] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    43.836] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    43.836] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event9)
[    43.836] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    43.836] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    43.836] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Line Out (/dev/input/event7)
[    43.836] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    43.836] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    43.837] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Rear Mic (/dev/input/event5)
[    43.837] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    43.837] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    43.837] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel MID Line (/dev/input/event6)
[    43.837] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    43.837] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    43.837] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Barcode Reader  (/dev/input/event2)
[    43.837] (**) Barcode Reader : Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    43.837] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Barcode Reader '
[    43.837] (**) Barcode Reader : always reports core events
[    43.837] (**) evdev: Barcode Reader : Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    43.837] (--) evdev: Barcode Reader : Vendor 0x13ba Product 0x18
[    43.837] (--) evdev: Barcode Reader : Found keys
[    43.837] (II) evdev: Barcode Reader : Configuring as keyboard
[    43.837] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/0003:13BA:0018.0001/input/input5/event2"
[    43.837] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Barcode Reader " (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    43.837] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    43.837] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    43.837] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    43.838] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Barcode Reader  (/dev/input/event3)
[    43.838] (**) Barcode Reader : Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    43.838] (**) Barcode Reader : Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    43.838] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Barcode Reader '
[    43.838] (**) Barcode Reader : always reports core events
[    43.838] (**) evdev: Barcode Reader : Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    43.838] (--) evdev: Barcode Reader : Vendor 0x13ba Product 0x18
[    43.838] (--) evdev: Barcode Reader : Found 9 mouse buttons
[    43.838] (--) evdev: Barcode Reader : Found scroll wheel(s)
[    43.838] (--) evdev: Barcode Reader : Found relative axes
[    43.838] (--) evdev: Barcode Reader : Found x and y relative axes
[    43.838] (--) evdev: Barcode Reader : Found absolute axes
[    43.838] (II) evdev: Barcode Reader : Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[    43.838] (--) evdev: Barcode Reader : Found keys
[    43.838] (II) evdev: Barcode Reader : Configuring as mouse
[    43.838] (II) evdev: Barcode Reader : Configuring as keyboard
[    43.838] (II) evdev: Barcode Reader : Adding scrollwheel support
[    43.838] (**) evdev: Barcode Reader : YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    43.838] (**) evdev: Barcode Reader : EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    43.838] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.1/0003:13BA:0018.0002/input/input6/event3"
[    43.838] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Barcode Reader " (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    43.838] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    43.838] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    43.838] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    43.838] (II) evdev: Barcode Reader : initialized for relative axes.
[    43.838] (WW) evdev: Barcode Reader : ignoring absolute axes.
[    43.838] (**) Barcode Reader : (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    43.838] (**) Barcode Reader : (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    43.838] (**) Barcode Reader : (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    43.838] (**) Barcode Reader : (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    43.839] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Barcode Reader  (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    43.839] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    43.839] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    43.839] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
[    43.839] (**) USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    43.839] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB Optical Mouse'
[    43.839] (**) USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[    43.839] (**) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    43.891] (--) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Vendor 0x17ef Product 0x602e
[    43.891] (--) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    43.891] (--) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    43.891] (--) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[    43.891] (--) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[    43.891] (II) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[    43.891] (II) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[    43.891] (**) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    43.891] (**) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    43.891] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/0003:17EF:602E.0003/input/input7/event4"
[    43.891] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[    43.891] (II) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[    43.891] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    43.891] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    43.891] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    43.891] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    43.891] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    43.891] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    43.891] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): connected
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    51.027] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): connected
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.347] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    63.555] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): connected
[    63.555] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    63.555] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    63.555] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    63.555] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    63.555] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    63.555] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    63.556] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    63.556] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    63.556] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    63.556] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): connected
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    63.591] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    63.639] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): connected
[    63.639] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    63.639] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    63.639] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    63.639] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    63.640] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    63.640] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    63.640] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    63.640] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    63.640] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    63.640] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): connected
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BenQ G925HDA (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    64.699] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

Blendr System Settings under User Preferences has a feature where I can assign the compute device to be the CPU or GPU. After installing the driver for the GPU, the system settings does not prompt me to use the GPU instead of the CPU as Blendr does not seem to detect the GPU. I did not try anything to make it detect the GPU other than install the GPU drivers.

Comment: As per your comment, I have edited the question. Please check if the problem is clearer now! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -r`, `find /lib/modules -name nvidia\*.ko\*`, `lsmod | grep nvidia`, and `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA` as well as the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`? Thanks.

Comment: The system replies have been added as per the commands you provided. Waiting for your feedback! Thanks!

Comment: I requested the *content* of the log file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, not the output of an attempt to execute it. ;-) The output of all the command looks good insofar as your system uses the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers. Which application specifically doesn't detect the graphics hardware acceleration? What exactly did you try to have the application detect it?

Comment: Thanks David! Blendr System Settings under User Preferences has a feature where I can assign the compute device to be the CPU or GPU. After installing the driver for the GPU, the system settings does not prompt me to use the GPU instead of the CPU as Blendr does not seem to detect the GPU. I did not try anything to make it detect the GPU

Comment: Could you please add that info to your question too? It's best to have everything relevant in one place so potential answerers don't have to go through the comments. Also, are you sure that's the entire content of `Xorg.0.log`? It looks a bit cut off. Maybe you hit the max. character limit for questions? Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks David! The contents of the Xorg.0.log is complete. The editor as of yet has not asked me to use the pastie service for long pasted content in the question.

Comment: The nvidia driver is clearly installed.  If you [installed it properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau/481540#481540) then it appears that your question is really "How do I get Blendr to utilize my Nvidia GPU?" You may find [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles) useful.

Comment: @Renato A Thanks for the enlightment! :) There has been no marked performance enhancements on my graphic acceleration whether I use Ubuntu defaults or Nvidia software. It is not related to Blendr alone, other editing programs exhibit similar performance on both drivers!

Comment: @David Should I go with a fresh installation of Ubuntu on my system & check whether Ubuntu runs the default NVIDIA drivers?

Comment: @ElderGeek I have not been able to blacklist the default Ubuntu GPU drivers as my system says it can not find the 'vim' command. Do you think the crux of the issue is the blacklist.conf instructions. Would you point me the exact steps to get the drivers blacklisted without 'vim'. Thanks!

Comment: @AngshumanMishra vim is just a text editor. You may use whatever text editor you want whether that be gedit, pluma, emacs, leafpad, etc. etc. etc. Regardless of what instructions you are speaking of, the instructions for blacklisting do not require a specific editor. Or, you could simply install vim. Thanks for the comment, I needed a chuckle.  :-) At the risk of repeating myself, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau/481540#481540)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Nvidia driver instead nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not properly install blender](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376760/can-not-properly-install-blender)

Comment: A bad workman quarrels with his own tools! Linux is my own tool.. :) Thank you for the comments! The post are centered around my problem but not my exact problem. I am trying to get the system run on my older noveau driver once and do a fresh reinstallation of the nvidia drivers. I am using the bash history comand for this.