# Blender closes alone in ubuntu 13:10

Tags: blender

I installed Blender 2.69 via ppa in ubuntu saucy salamander using a ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
```

But it closes randomly when I am using it. I was wondering if anyone has a solution to this, was it because of the ppa? How can I fix it?

Comment: Which ppa are you using? You might also want to look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110821/how-to-install-blender-from-the-official-website)

Comment: I used this ppa: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender

Comment: You can also install from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/blender/) - is it backing up files regularly that causes the problem, or does it close at random?

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problems. Using 13.10 and ppa:irie/blender Blender crashes every time I left-click on anything. (which means it is useless)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! I downloaded Blender from the website and installed manually. Now it works very well!