# How to resolve pycuda installation error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda"?

Tags: installation, compiling

I am installing pycuda2011.2.2 on ubuntu 11.10, but can't complete it. Cuda is 4.0. When I do:

```
$ make -j 4
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcurand.so when searching for -lcurand
```

Why this error? I think that cuda is 32 bit on 64 bit machine. But I can't see whether it's 32 bit or 64 bit.

Also, can anyone share code to make "gcc 4.4" as priority, just for my account and not all account?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would want to run `make` at all when building pycuda - it does not even have a `Makefile` (apart from the documentation).

You install *pycuda* by running `./configure.py` with the appropriate options followed by `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/nvidia-current python setup.py install`.

You need to set the `LDFLAGS` environment variable so that the pycuda setup can find `libcuda.so`, which on ubuntu systems is in a non-standard location (`/usr/lib/nvidia-current`).

If you're really asking about compiling the CUDA SDK (in which case you should definitely edit your question!), see my response [on the NVIDIA forums](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=213288&view=findpost&p=1426979).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `LDFLAGS='-L/usr/lib/nvidia-current'` ?

Comment: It should, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

What about removing `-lcuda` from the `Makefile`? Last time I checked the toolkit and sdk, I could not find a `libcuda.so` file.

There have also been changes in the strictness of the compiler, so `-lcuda` must come after object files and other libraries which depend on it. You likely have to move `-lcuda` to the end of the `$(CC)` line (or whatever compiler command is used).

Comment: I don't see -lcuda in Makefile.TRy this to find your libcuda.so:

Comment: Have you looked at http://askubuntu.com/q/131506/6969 for installing CUDA? A default installation does not work properly (at least, not for me on 12.04)

Comment: sorry, I left comment open and it got published.Try this to find your libcuda.so: ......@ubuntu:/usr$ locate libcuda.so =>
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so . Also, Can you please elaborate what you said before ? CUDA is already installed on machine which i got, so i don't know if its just default or not.

Comment: i haven't checked that thread as CUDA is already installed.

Comment: @user55717 Check the SDK installation part on http://askubuntu.com/a/133869/6969, it mentions some changes that you need to perform to get the CUDA toolkit and compiler working in 12.04.

Comment: I opened common.mk but it won't let me modify even if I have sudo access.Every time it opens new common.mk (common.mk(1), common.mk(2)...). I do see -lcuda there, which if removed, may relieve me of error. That file is in someone else's account. Is this why I can't modify ?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/121790/6969 for how to edit system files. Please upvote that answer if it helped you

Comment: Sorry, can't vote bcoz my reputation is less than 15. Once i get to 15 i will upvote it, if that helps. I couldn't modify bcoz of permission issue. Now i got write permission from user and modified file. Thanks for the link which has 'SDK installation part'. Turned out the user didn't did those modification. Now I did those modifications in 'common.mk', but still same error '-lcuda not found'. I will post a summary of my A-Z installation steps today. Really need to solve this issue. I appreciate your assiatance.

Comment: Use `grep` to find out what adds `-lcuda` and remove it.

Comment: I followed your article and removed -lcuda from "home/mmm/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/common.mk".  I found lcuda at many places.  One of them: ..../common/SAVE2012.05.25_common.mk:     LIB += -lcuda   ${OPENGLLIB} $(PARAMGLLIB) $(RENDERCHECKGLLIB) ${LIB}.   Shall i modify this and others like you mentioned in SDK article ?   In result of grep I saw this : /home/mmm/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/NVDIA_SDK.script:/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
. It explicitly mentioned that it can't find -lcuda. But I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: `-lcuda` means that the linker should link the binary to the cuda library (`libcuda.so`). I'd say, remove it.

Comment: -lcuda is in couple of files of directory C. It may be in other directories. Shall I remove -lcuda in all, and swap ${OPENGLLIB} and (RENDERCHECKGLLIB) in those files too ? like you mentioned in SDK portion of article.

Comment: I'd say, try it.

Comment: I got a therad that address same problem:<a href="http:// http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=224718&st=0#entry1413660"target=_blank>here</a>.Finally pycuda installed. I was about to try your suggestion, but that thread was a bullseye, so i didn't tried that.Lekensteyn, thanks a lot for continuous support.

Comment: unfortunately, i never found that thread till now.

Comment: @user55717 Hmm, last time I could not find that file, but now it's suddenly in my `/usr/lib/nvidia-current` folder. Glad that you've solved it.

Comment: i am glad too. Just tried to run pycuda example and it gave error. so i am trying to resolve it. Can that problem be discussed on ubuntu forum ?