# Will installing CUDA for my Nvidia card make OpenCL available?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, hybrid-graphics, opencl

I'm trying to use a program called 'pyrit' which can use OpenCL. When I run the program, I get this warning:

```
Failed to load Pyrit's OpenCL-core ('Failed to enumerate OpenCL-platforms (Unknown CLresult)')
```

(the code for pyrit to work with opencl has been successfully compiled and installed already)

I have an Nvidia Hybrid Optimus graphics card (geforce gt 630m), and I assume I need to *enable* OpenCL for it to work properly. I want to avoid CUDA if I can, but I don't know if that's an option.

I'm not sure what I need to do to enable OpenCL. Should I just follow the normal instructions for installing CUDA as described here? [How can I get nVidia CUDA or OpenCL working on a laptop with nVidia discrete card/Intel Integrated Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131506/how-can-i-get-nvidia-cuda-or-opencl-working-on-a-laptop-with-nvidia-discrete-car)