# How do I Make the Cuda 5.0 samples?

Tags: 12.04, cuda

I'm in much the same boat as PeterDC, who asked:

[How can I get nVidia CUDA or OpenCL working on a laptop with nVidia discrete card/Intel Integrated Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131506/how-can-i-get-nvidia-cuda-or-opencl-working-on-a-laptop-with-nvidia-discrete-car)

I've installed the toolkit & the samples, but cannot run `make` in the samples directory. When I try, I get:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/samples/0_Simple/simpleVoteIntrinsics'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/samples/0_Simple/simpleVoteIntrinsics'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/samples/0_Simple/simpleMPI'
Makefile:79: *** MPI not found, not building simpleMPI..  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/samples/0_Simple/simpleMPI'
make: *** [0_Simple/simpleMPI/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

Does this mean I need to edit the Makefile? Is this something I'm doing wrong, or Nvidia?

Comment: Editing the above to include more specifics.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know MPI was a separate package. I got it now. The command I needed was:

sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got the answer to this. (New to Linux!)

I needed to install the MPI library.

The requisite command was:

```
sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc
```

Then, going back to the samples directory, I entered:

```
make
```

And got the samples to build. Good luck & happy coding!