# Installing motherboard drivers

Tags: drivers

Yesterday I've successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 (x64), but something's bothering me, what about the drivers of my motherboard? I have the support DVD with the drivers of my motherboard, but I don't know where to start.

My motherboard is Rampage 3 Extreme.

Thank you for the responses...

Comment: There's nothing to install. All is in the Linux kernel. Why do you think you need additional drives? Ubuntu is not Windows.

Comment: As gertvdijk indicated, the drivers are in the kernel. Can you please update your question and describe any problem(s) you have or problem(s) you think you have.

Comment: Have you tried loading a LiveCD or a LiveUSB first?  If there's any kernel problems you can sometimes see whether they'll happen through the Live environment first.

Comment: Thank you for all your response, i thought i have to manualy install all of my mobo drivers... I'm new to ubuntu that's why the environment of ubuntu is completely new to me...

Comment: by the way, where can I view the kernel? do I have the capability to run one of my mobo's software, let's say "cpu level up"?

Comment: also my mobo has a bluetooth, how can I enable that? is it already installed in the kernel?

Comment: @josapedmoreno Ask a NEW question if you need help getting Bluetooth to work specifically. Then include specific hardware information about your Bluetooth device.

Comment: How do we know that the drivers that came with the kernel are not barebone. they are good enough for your computer to run, but its not good for gaming

Comment: if linux kernel came with all the very latest drivers, it wouldnt weight 500mb, it would weight around 9-11 gigabytes

Answer (score 5):

You usually don't need to install any driver after installing a Linux distribution like Ubuntu, but you should always check with the application [Additional Drivers](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/jockey-gtk/) if there is any thing that can be installed to improve your computer performance.

The rare cases that you need to install a driver is when you have a video-card like NVIDIA and others like that.

Comment: Yes I do have an NVIDIA card... I also want to install the 3d driver of nvidia for my monitor... how can I do that? thanks...

Comment: @josapedmoreno [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/301648/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu) contains the information you need. Please dot not forget to mark the answer as the correct.