# Installing Nvidia Additional Driver failed in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I have a GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 graphics card installed in an HP Compaq Presario CQ5000 Series desktop with an AMD Athlon II X3 435 processor, 2GB RAM and Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit installed. I tried to install the NVIDIA driver from the Additional Drivers window for the recommended driver Nvidia 304 (Nvidia web recommends version 325, but says it is better to use the recommended Ubuntu driver!), but it failed!, and I need a driver to use Unity (3D). Thanks in advance for your help.

This is the content in the jockey.log file:

```
2014-03-14 18:52:35,784 DEBUG: Installing package: nvidia-304
2014-03-14 18:52:36,540 ERROR: Binary package nvidia-304 has no trusted origin, rejecting
2014-03-14 18:52:36,786 WARNING: modinfo for module nvidia_304 failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module nvidia_304

2014-03-14 18:52:36,788 ERROR: XorgDriverHandler.enable(): package or module not installed, aborting
2014-03-14 18:52:36,805 ERROR: xorg:nvidia_304: get_alternative_by_name(nvidia-304) returned nothing ....etc.
```

Comment: The nvidia 173 is the driver for that card. You can also use the Nouveau driver. You can only have one driver installed at a time. You may have to experiment to see which one works best, the Nouveau driver has been getting better in the last two years.

Comment: NO, I am installing the Driver from the Aditional Driver Window and use the recomended Driver, Then I will use the 173 driver and will tell you the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this jobs step and it works! :

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic  (was already installed)

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo reboot

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

sudo nvidia-xconfig

sudo reboot

and thats all, install nvidia 304 driver and could use MyUnity perfectly !!!

(based on [How to install NVIDIA driver in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301648/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu)  by Max Tither)