# NVIDIA 560 TI driver install ubuntu 14.04 leads to "missing on display" error

Tags: nvidia, 14.04

Currently on my Ubuntu 14.04 install, I boot it up install the latest updates and attempt to install the NVIDIA drivers from xorg-edgers while following the top answer on this post [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers)

It installs 304 for my card and when I check the `"glxinfo | grep OpenGL"` I have about 8 lines that read

```
Xlib: extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

I did the "sudo apt-get install nvidia-current" to get the latest. I install it but didn't see any errors in the terminal. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm not a complete beginner with Linux so I can find my way around just fine but I can't find a solution to this issue.

Should I have done one of these two instead?

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304

sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-304
```

Comment: you need to clarify whether you want to use ppa or default from Ubuntu repos? what do you exactly want. The latest Nvidia driver for 500series is 331.79

Comment: If you want my opinion, playing with video drivers is tricky I don't trust ppa for video graphics only official Ubuntu packages or Nvidia(my choice) itself.

Comment: in all honestly I'm just trying to get the installation to USE the graphics card. I've only tried installing via the PPA and haven't had any luck so I'll probably do it via official packages. How does one do that? Just download it from the NVIDIA site and install the .run file?

Comment: I am just going to link you some links, and hopefully they can help you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/301648/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu , http://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver

Comment: here's workaround I use http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file/423619#423619 you can read it all for your information, there's workaround written by me also for 12.04 but works with 14.04 too, I just manually installed today the Nvidia driver it works for now :-) because there were incompatibilities with linux kernels but seems ok now. Download driver from here http://www.geforce.com/drivers choose `certified` in list.

Comment: don't forget to disable ppa you've added for nvidia to avoid conflicts :-)

Comment: I followed your directions JohnnyEnglish and it worked! Thanks! My next goal is to get Steam running so hopefully that's a bit easier to figure out than this in the first place.