# Can't get Diablo 3 to work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I've tried launching Diablo 3 through playonlinux and it always crashes after "Retrieving Hero List"

I have the latest version of Wine and I've tried:

- using the Setarch command
- putting "-opengl" in the arguments.

And it still crashes. I'd really like to play the game.

I am VERY NEW to Ubuntu 14.04 and any Linux based operating system so if you tell me to put in some kind of command in the terminal please if you can go into detail because I am almost clueless as to how I even get to things on here. Just a fair warning I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Please review the edits I made to your post to get better answers...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is how I fixed it:

1. Update to the latest graphics drivers:

   - Check your kernel version by typing in terminal `uname -r`. I had a problem with driver after installing kernel 3.19. (Currently I'm using 3.13-generic.)
   - for ATI see [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124292/175814)
   - for nVidia see [How to install NVIDIA driver in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/301648/175814)
2. Reboot.
3. Install Wine 1.6 from `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install wine1.6
   ```
4. Install Battle.net and Diablo 3.
5. If your launcher is crashing after 10-20 seconds:

   - Open `winecfg` (wine configuration).
   - In the *Application* tab click *Add applications* and add `Diablo 3 launcher.exe` and `Diablo 3.exe`.
   - Let `Diablo 3 launcher.exe` selected and go to the *Libraries* tab. In *New override for library* type `dbghelp` and click *Add* and *yes*.
     In *Existing overrides* select `dbghelp`, click *Edit*, and set it to *Disable*.
   - Go back to the *Applications* tab and select `Diablo 3.exe`. Go to the *Libraries* tab again and in *New override for library* type `dbghelp` and click *Add** and *yes*.
     In *Existing overrides* select `dbghelp`, click *Edit* and set it to *built-in*.
   - Click *Ok*.
6. Launch the game using command

   ```
   wine "location of the game" -launch-opengl
   ```

Comment: I removed some of the package installation commands, because they were redundant. `wine1.6` already depends on all the necessary packages for *both* architectures. The Wine PPA doesn't have any newer stable packages than Canonical's repositories. It would be better to use written instead of video instruction and cite the relevant parts of external resources. Please read [How to write good answers](/help/how-to-answer) and use better formatting (espc. for code listings) the next time.