# Who is behind nvidia.ko?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, 14.10

Were the files nvidia.ko and nvidia-uvm.ko loaded by the Ubuntu update or were they made by the NVidia corporation?

Explanation of question:
    Consider 2 files that I installed - 
       (1) nvidia.ko
       (2) nvidia-uvm.ko
    Tell me who created these files, the Linux OS or the nVidia Corp.

Comment: Sounds like generated files. If you have installed one of the `nvidia-*-uvm` packages, it is likely they are binary drivers provided from nVidia via Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I manually loaded the nVidia proprietary drivers, then a Ubuntu kernal and C-lib update destroyed the launcher, dash, ... I am trying to fix instead of reload. Understanding the source of these files is one direction in understanding the bug.

Comment: Try to install the nvidia drivers from the [xorg-edgers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install NVIDIA driver in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/301648/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @ElderGeek Where is the OP asking how to install Nvidia drivers here?

Comment: @Seth The comment the OP made yesterday indicated that he manually loaded the drivers and was trying to fix them. I thought perhaps they hadn't been loaded properly and that the link provided would cover that. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @Seth, Thanks for the comment. I kinda had the same question for Sylvain. I am trouble shooting problems from an update that took away my launcher, dash, terminal, menu, and resolution. I reinstalled drivers, compared all of the files that changed between the update and proprietary drivers and found that nvidia made the suspect files. Though, the files did not cause the problems, which still exist.

Comment: Consider the question answered. I have to wait 2 more hours before I can accept my own answer.

Comment: As of 2013 The NVIDIA Unified Kernel Memory module is a kernel module for a Unified Memory feature exposed by a release of NVIDIA's CUDA. The module is nvidia-uvm.ko Source:http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQ5NDc

Comment: The kernel module (nvidia.ko) consists of a proprietary part (commonly known as the "binary blob") which drives the graphics chip(s), and an open source part (the "glue") which at runtime acts as intermediary between the proprietary part and the kernel. These all need to work nicely together as otherwise the user might be faced with data loss (through kernel panics, X servers crashing with unsaved data in X applications) and even hardware failure. Source: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NVidia/nvidia-drivers

Comment: Excellent response and nice resource (wiki.gentoo.org).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The files were generated upon installing the nVidia proprietary drivers.