# Nvidia-304 driver not installing correctly on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, lubuntu, xorg

For the past day I have trying to get the Nvidia drivers to work on my 10 year old PC running Lubuntu 16.04.6 LTS as recommended [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521367/graphichs-driver-issue-for-nvidia-geforce-7100-nforce-630i?noredirect=1#comment963640_521367). The automatically installed drivers did not work, so I typed `glxinfo` and all I got was

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

I have trawled the internet, following guides such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301648/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu) and many more very similar ones, mostly advising me to install `nvidia-304` as opposed to `nvidia-304-updates`, the only two differences I can see between the two is that the `nvidia-304-updates` package runs at 800x600 resolution whereas the `nvidia-304` package runs at (I think) 1280x800. My monitor's resolution is 1280x1024. More importantly, when running the last command in that sequence `sudo nvidia-xconfig` I get left with this:

```
Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

But that's besides the point. **why are the graphics drivers not installing correctly, and how do I install them correctly?**

FYI here are my system specs **copy-pasted off my linked question, ignore OS, Kernel etc**:

```
System information report, generated by Sysinfo: 27/05/2019 17:18:20
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsysinfo

SYSTEM INFORMATION
    Running LinuxMint Linux, the LinuxMint 19.1 (tessa) release.
    GNOME: 3.28.2 (Ubuntu)
    Kernel version: 4.15.0-20-generic (#21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018)
    GCC: 7 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    Xorg: 1.19.6 (25 October 2018  04:11:27PM) (25 October 2018  04:11:27PM)
    Hostname: jeremy-ixtreme-M3720
    Uptime: 0 days 0 h 49 min

CPU INFORMATION
    GenuineIntel, Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q8300  @ 2.50GHz
    Number of CPUs: 4
    CPU clock currently at 2000.092 MHz with 2048 KB cache
    Numbering: family(6) model(23) stepping(10)
    Bogomips: 4999.94
    Flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm

MEMORY INFORMATION
    Total memory: 7724 MB
    Total swap: 2047 MB

STORAGE INFORMATION
    SCSI device -  scsi3
        Vendor:  ATAPI    
        Model:  DVD A  DH16AASH  
    SCSI device -  scsi4
        Vendor:  ATA      
        Model:  ADATA SU650      
    SCSI device -  scsi6
        Vendor:  Generic  
        Model:  USB SD Reader    
    SCSI device -  scsi6
        Vendor:  Generic  
        Model:  USB CF Reader    

HARDWARE INFORMATION
MOTHERBOARD
    Host bridge
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 Host Bridge (rev a2)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] MCP73 Host Bridge
    PCI bridge(s)
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    ISA bridge
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] MCP73 LPC Bridge
    IDE interface
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 IDE Controller (rev a1) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] MCP73 IDE Controller

GRAPHIC CARD
    VGA controller
        NVIDIA Corporation C73 [GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] C73 [GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i]

SOUND CARD
    Multimedia controller
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 High Definition Audio (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] MCP73 High Definition Audio

NETWORK
    Ethernet controller
        Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
```

EDIT 1:
The graphical installer comes up with the same errors.

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: **If** you're actually using Lubuntu 16.04 just open Additional Drivers, select and apply the 304 version. Reboot.

Comment: How about you post the output of `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: Just fire-up Synaptic search on Nvidia and install from there. Trying to install from "Additional Drivers" and it just hangs there forever.