# VGA controller showing integrated graphics card not nvidia card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, python, cuda

I've recently installed Cuda and, as far as I'm aware, it is working correctly.

which nvcc returns

```
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc
```

running tf.Session() returns

```
2017-06-16 16:56:24.119619: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-16 16:56:24.119682: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-16 16:56:24.119698: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-16 16:56:24.119711: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-16 16:56:24.119724: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-16 16:56:24.249220: E 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:406] failed call to 
cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
2017-06-16 16:56:24.249294: I 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:145] kernel driver 
does not appear to be running on this host: /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
```

dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia  returns

[image]

nvidia-smi, however, returns

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. 
Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

and

lspci -v | grep "VGA controller" returns

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

which seems to indicate that the nvidia isn't being used?

Could someone point me in the right direction to getting this sorted?

Thank you very much

EDIT: IMPORTANT

nvidia-settings reported that the NVIDIA driver is not loaded and that it could not find the registry key file

Answer (score 0):

nvidia is known for being buggy with linix. you need the proprietary drivers. 
the most common nvidia drivers are available in the restricted/non-free repo.
istalling the drivers should fix all the nvidia issues.

Comment: Will this not cause issue with my cuda installation?

Comment: I don't think so.the last line you posted shows that it is looking for the driver. >>>>tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:145] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host: /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exis

Comment: I found this, maybe it will help.  https://askubuntu.com/a/134961/694267